# A space is missing in the design of the opinion-based post notice

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

It lies before the "If..." sentence.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. Fix for this is waiting in repo for next build. Should be live in couple hours.

Comment: can I see the repo? Also, I suggest to change the last link to "edit it" to avoid redundancy